# Creating SQL Server JSON Parsing/Query UDF

Tags: sql-server, json, string-parsing

First of all before I get into the question, I'll preface this with the fact that I know that this is a "bad" idea.  But for business reasons it is something that I have to come up with a solution to, and I'm hoping that someone, somewhere might have some ideas on how to go about this.

I have a SQL Server 2008 R2 table that has a "OtherProperties" column.  This column contains various other, somewhat arbitrary additional pieces of information that relate to the records.  There is a business need to create a UDF that we can use to query the results, for example.

```
SELECT *
FROM MyTable
WHERE MyUDFGetValue(myTable.OtherProperties, "LinkedOrder[0]") IS NOT NULL
```

This would find a record where there was an array of LinkedOrder entries that contained a value at index 0

```
SELECT *
FROM MyTable
WHERE MyUDFGetValue(myTable.OtherProperties, "SubOrder.OrderId") = 25
```

This would find a property "orderId" and use its value in a comparison.

Anyone seen an implementation of this?  I've seen implementations of functions.  Like this [JSONParser](http://www.simple-talk.com/sql/t-sql-programming/consuming-json-strings-in-sql-server/) that take the values into a table which just will not get us what we need query wise.  Complexity wise, I don't want to write a full fledged JSON parser, but I can if I need to.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Parse JSON in TSQL](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2867501/parse-json-in-tsql)

Answer (score 2):

Not sure if this will suit your needs but I read about a CLR JSON serializer/deserializer. You can find it here, http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/CLR/74160/

Comment: This is somewhat helpful, but I really need to get native parsing/querying on JSON columns...but this is a good find!

Answer (score 2):

It's been a long time since you asked your question but there is now a solution you can use - [JSON Select](https://jsonselect.joshuahealy.net/) which provides various functions for different datatypes, for example the `JsonInt()` function.  From one of your examples (assuming OrderId is an int, if not you could use a different function):

```
SELECT *
FROM MyTable
WHERE dbo.JsonInt(myTable.OtherProperties, 'SubOrder.OrderId') = 25
```

DISCLOSURE:
I am the author of JSON Select, and as such have an interest in you using it :)

Answer (score 1):

If you cannot use SQL Server 2016 with built-in JSON support, you would need to use CLR e.g. JSONselect, json4sql, or custom code such as http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1000953/JSON-for-SQL-Server-Part, etc.