# Can you use SQL to SELECT values from a JSON array?

Tags: sql, sql-server, arrays, json

I have a database in SQL Server 2008 and one particular table has information stored in fields as JSON-encoded arrays.  I'm wondering there's a SQL-based approach to select out specific values within that JSON field?

I can, of course, just select the field and parse the information out myself, but I'm trying to avoid that if at all possible.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There's nothing natively, but the first answer on the follow question references an article about parsing JSON objects in tSQL

[Parse JSON in TSQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2867501/parse-json-in-tsql)

For reference, the article of interest is here:

http://www.simple-talk.com/sql/t-sql-programming/consuming-json-strings-in-sql-server/

Comment: Wow, the guy who wrote that article deserves our respect! @tbone14, this can be your solution, if you can add user-defined functions to the database.

Comment: There is [native support](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn921900.aspx) starting from SQL Server 2016.

Answer (score 2):

**No** (well, there's substring matching, but that would be slow and error-prone). If you're storing something you want to filter with SQL, do not use JSON, use separate columns/tables instead.

Comment: I have no control over the database structure or how information is stored.  I'm just the integrator -_-