# Parse JSON string in sql

Tags: sql, sql-server, json, sql-server-2008

I have a column of JSON strings in my table, I'm using SQL Server 2008.
Any Ideas on how to parse the JSON string and extract a specific value?

Here's my JSON String:

```
{"id":1234,"name":"Lasagne al frono","description":"Placerat nisi turpis, dictumst nasceture ete etiam mus nec cum platea tempori zillest. Nisi niglue, augue adipiscing ete dignissim sed mauris augue, eros!","image":"images/EmptyProduct.jpg","cartImage":"images/ArabianCoffee.jpg","basePrice":54.99,"priceAttribute":"itemPrice","attributes":[{"type":"Addons","label":"Side","attributeName":"Side","display":"Small","lookupId":8},{"type":"Addons","label":"Drink","attributeName":"drink","display":"Small","lookupId":5},{"label":"add note","type":"Text","attributeName":"notes","display":"Wide","lookupId":null}]}
```

I need to extract the value of "name", Any Help?

Comment: Almost dup of [Parse JSON in TSQL](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2867501/1178314), which asks with a parameter as a source instead of a column, but have good answers and now mention the native JSON support in SQL Server 2016.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Since sql server has no JSON support built in, you'd need to parse this manually, which would get complicated.

However, you could always use somebody else's [JSON parsing library](http://www.simple-talk.com/sql/t-sql-programming/consuming-json-strings-in-sql-server/).

Answer (score 2):

For parsing JSON you can write an easy [CLR Function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189876.aspx) in C# or VB.NET.

Answer (score 2):

Now you can use MS SQL Server 2016

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn921897.aspx