# JSON data handling in SQL Server

Tags: jquery, sql, sql-server, json

I have a Json string. I Want to get value from that Json string.

This is my json string
`{"latitude":"22.5712854"},{"longitude":"88.4266847"}`

I want only `latitude` and `longitude` from this, using TSQL query.

Comment: This could help you: https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/t-sql-programming/consuming-json-strings-in-sql-server/

Comment: TSQL can't parse JSON natively and it's a very weak language for text parsing and handling in general (although you could parse the string you've shown using only `SUBSTRING` and `CHARINDEX`). It will almost certainly be easier to do this using code outside the database or possibly a CLR procedure; that way you can use a language that has JSON support or at least good text processing functions.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Parse JSON in TSQL](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2867501/parse-json-in-tsql)

Comment: Check the [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2867501/parse-json-in-tsql) duplicated here as flagged by AndrewC. Its answers are more thorough and it mentions the native `JSON` support in SQL Server 2016.

Answer (score 5):

There is no native way to parse JSON in TSQL. But Phil Factor  created his own implementation of paring JSON in SQL function. More about it on simple talk blog in article: [Consuming JSON Strings in SQL Server](https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/t-sql-programming/consuming-json-strings-in-sql-server/)

Aslo Ric Vander Ark created his own function but I did not tested it. You can read more on article: [A Function to Split JSON Data](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/JSON/68128/)

Comment: "There is no native way to parse JSON in TSQL. But Phil Factor created his own implementation [to parse JSON in TSQL]" <-- Contradiction at its best. Still, thanks for the link on how to parse JSON in TSQL. :)

Comment: A custom implementation, as listed is different to a native (i.e. built in) way.

Answer (score 0):

You could use [JSON Select](https://jsonselect.joshuahealy.net/) which has several functions for extracting different datatypes from JSON. For your requirements you could do something like this:

```
select 
    dbo.JsonDecimal(my_column, 'latitude') as latitude,
    dbo.JsonDecimal(my_column, 'longitude') as longitude
from my_table
```

DISCLOSURE: I am the author of JSON Select, and as such have an interest in you using it :)