# SQL Server 2014 get data from JSON column

Tags: sql, sql-server, json

I have a table with many columns, one of them contains JSON structured data,
for example:

```
{"firstname": "john", "lastname": "tim"}
```

I need to get all the `lastname` data.

Any suggestions?

Comment: the downvotes are probably because you are not saying what you have tried and there are plenty of options from google (or SO https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23723473/query-json-inside-sql-server-2012-column). are you looking for someting better than string processing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one more way for reading the `lastname` data from `JSON` :

```
SELECT REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(DATA, '}', ''), '"lastname":', ''), '"', '') [LastName]
FROM
(
    SELECT split.a.value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') DATA
    FROM
    (
        SELECT CAST('<A>'+REPLACE(<jsoncolumn>, ',', '</A><A>')+'</A>' AS XML) AS String
        FROM <table_name>
    ) A
    CROSS APPLY String.nodes('/A') AS split(a)
) AA
WHERE AA.DATA LIKE '%lastname%';
```

Result :

```
LastName
tim
```