# Any pre-req to use JSON.sql or steps to install JSON.sql?

Tags: sql, json, sql-server-2008

I wanted to parse a string in JSON on a SQL Server 2008 R2 instance.

I read this awesome article by [Phil](https://stackoverflow.com/users/62661/phil-factor) over [here](https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/t-sql-programming/consuming-json-strings-in-sql-server/) and also looked at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2867501/parse-json-in-tsql) SO question.

I downloaded the [JSON.sql](https://www.simple-talk.com/content/file.ashx?file=10152) from simpletalk site and tried running on my local SQL Server instance.

But I got errors - (pasting it as such)

> Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 1
>   Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'AS'.
>
> Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Procedure ToJSON, Line 6
>   Incorrect syntax near 'READONLY'.
>
> Msg 1087, Level 15, State 2, Procedure ToJSON, Line 67
>   Must declare the table variable "@Hierarchy".
>
> Msg 1087, Level 15, State 2, Procedure ToJSON, Line 90
>   Must declare the table variable "@Hierarchy".
>
> Msg 178, Level 15, State 1, Procedure ToJSON, Line 98
>   A RETURN statement with a return value cannot be used in this context.
>
> Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Procedure ToXML, Line 6
>   Incorrect syntax near 'READONLY'.
>
> Msg 1087, Level 15, State 2, Procedure ToXML, Line 29
>   Must declare the table variable "@hierarchy".
>
> Msg 1087, Level 15, State 2, Procedure ToXML, Line 43
>   Must declare the table variable "@hierarchy".
>
> Msg 1087, Level 15, State 2, Procedure ToXML, Line 47
>   Must declare the table variable "@hierarchy".
>
> Msg 1087, Level 15, State 2, Procedure ToXML, Line 53
>   Must declare the table variable "@hierarchy".
>
> Msg 178, Level 15, State 1, Procedure ToXML, Line 65
>   A RETURN statement with a return value cannot be used in this context.

Is there anything I need to do before running JSON.sql?

Edit:When I checked SQL Server version using SSMS....Help --> About, it showed the following [image: SQL Server 2008 R2]

After @marc_s suggestion checked the version using @@version command. Surprisingly this showed my instance to be thus [image: SQL Server 2005.]

Any idea what could be happening?

Comment: Are you **sure** your local SQL Server instance is at least version **2008** ? That's where the table-valued parameters have been introduced (which seems to cause these errors). Run `SELECT @@VERSION` on your instance to see what engine version you're working with

Comment: Try to execute JSON.sql in small batches and see where the first error occurs. That is: select SQL code before first "GO" command and execute it (press F5).

Comment: @marc_s Thanks. Can you write the comment which you wrote as answer so that I could accept it as the right answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you sure your local SQL Server instance is at least version **2008**?

That's where the table-valued parameters have been introduced (which seems to cause these errors judging from the error mentioning the `READONLY` keyword).

Run `SELECT @@VERSION` on your instance to see what engine version you're working with. You might have the **Management Tools** 2008 or 2008 R2, but your engine might still be a SQL Server **2005** - and the features (like table-valued parameter) really depends more on the **engine** rather than the management tools (most of the time).