# Split JSON data in SQL Server column

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table in SQL Server which has an `address` column of string datatype.

Address values like

```
{"line1":"Nav Place Road","line2":"Nyork City","line3":"USA 34576"}
```

I want to get result in a separate column `line1, line2, line3, line4` with select query.

I try with split function, but I can't get proper result.

Comment: Don't store multiple values like this in a single column - this **violates** the **first normal form** of database design

Comment: so your address column contain like this , right ?

line1:Nav Place Road,line2:Nyork City,line3:USA 34576

Comment: See https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/t-sql-programming/consuming-json-strings-in-sql-server/

Comment: @marc_s Or to put it another way, it's *fine* to store multiple values in a column like this. But don't expect access to them from a SQL query; only from your client application.

Comment: Stored as XML would be better; at least you could query it then.

Comment: @marc_s What would be the best way to store keywords for a product/article in a relational DB? Especially if the number of keywords you can input is not limited?

Comment: @RaduGheorghiu: add a separate `keywords` table that contains keywords (any number of them) with a link to the `Product` or `Article` table. Just a simple, basic, nicely relational 1:n relationship.....

Comment: @marc_s Thank you, I have to get my knowledge of RDBs back on track.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Parse JSON in TSQL](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2867501/parse-json-in-tsql)

Answer (score 2):

You could use [JSON Select](https://jsonselect.joshuahealy.net/) which providers several functions for extracting different datatypes from JSON.  For your example you could do something like this:

```
select 
    dbo.JsonNVarChar450(address, 'line1') as line1,
    dbo.JsonNVarChar450(address, 'line2') as line2,
    dbo.JsonNVarChar450(address, 'line3') as line3
from your_table
```

DISCLOSURE:
I am the author of JSON Select, and as such have an interest in you using it :)