# Insert json data with repeated columns to sql server

Tags: c#, sql-server, json

I have a JSON Data with Repeated columns with differenet data I need to insert at a time in to sql Server.Here CommonCategoryRowId is same and CommonCategoryAttributeName  will change

Here is the sample of JSON Data

```
"[{\"CommonCategoryAttributeName\":\"Gopal\",\"CommonCategoryRowId\":1},{\"CommonCategoryAttributeName\":\"Reddy\",\"CommonCategoryRowId\":1},{\"CommonCategoryAttributeName\":\"vinnamala\",\"CommonCategoryRowId\":1}]"
```

Answer (score 0):

There's a answer that deals with something similar here [Parse JSON in TSQL](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24396355/4352356)
If refers to an article here [Consuming JSON Strings in SQL Server](https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/t-sql-programming/consuming-json-strings-in-sql-server/)

Using the function above, you can parse your JSON into a table, and then select from there to do your insert

```
SELECT *
INTO #Tmp
FROM dbo.parseJSON(
'[
{"CommonCategoryAttributeName":"Gopal","CommonCategoryRowId":1},
{"CommonCategoryAttributeName":"Reddy","CommonCategoryRowId":1},
{"CommonCategoryAttributeName":"vinnamala","CommonCategoryRowId":1}]"') data
WHERE Object_id is NULL

SELECT a.StringValue, b.StringValue
FROM #Tmp a
    LEFT JOIN #Tmp b ON b.Name = 'CommonCategoryAttributeName' AND a.Parent_id = b.parent_id
WHERE a.Name = 'CommonCategoryRowId'
```

And this is the result

Hope that helps

```
1   Gopal
1   Reddy
1   vinnamala
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public string PartyID(Stream ABC)//json that i posted
    {   
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();

        string response = string.Empty;
        try
        {
            string Json = string.Empty;

            StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(ABC);
            dynamic param = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<dynamic>(sr.ReadToEnd());


            string CommonCategoryAttributeName= param.CommonCategoryAttributeName;
            string CommonCategoryRowId= param.CommonCategoryRowId;

            string[] commonCategoryAttributeName= CommonCategoryAttributeName.Split(new char[] { ',' });


            DataTable tbl = new DataTable();
            tbl.Columns.Add("CommonCategoryAttributeName", typeof(string));
            tbl.Columns.Add("CommonCategoryRowId", typeof(long));



            for (int i = 0; i < CommonCategoryAttributesRowId.Length; i++)
            {
                tbl.Rows.Add(CommonCategoryAttributeName[i], commonCategoryRowId);
            }

            string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(tbl, Formatting.None);
            json = Regex.Unescape(json);

            dt = (DataTable)JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(json.Trim(new Char[] { ' ', '"', '.' }), typeof(DataTable));

            SqlParameter[] parameters = { new SqlParameter("@commonAttributes", dt) };
            int result = yourclass.ExecuteNonQuery(null, CommandType.StoredProcedure, "commonID", parameters);

        }


        catch (Exception Ex)
        {

        }
        return response;
    }
```