# Transform JSON data to separate columns

Tags: sql, sql-server, json, database

I have following DB structure:

```
ID  Name  Value
1   TV1   {"URL": "www.url.com", "Icon": "some_icon"}
2   TV2   {"URL": "www.url.com", "Icon": "some_icon", "Facebook": "Facebook_URL"}
3   TV3   {"URL": "www.url.com", "Icon": "some_icon", "Twitter": "Twitter_URL"}
..........
```

I am looking for a query with the native functions of SQL Server 2012 to extract the JSON from the column `Value`, and dynamically create columns, and I want to do this for different count of columns *without hard coding the column names `name`, `icon`, `twitter`, `facebook`*. So the result I am looking for like:

```
ID  Name  URL          Icon           Facebook      Twitter
1   TV1   www.url.com  some_icon          NULL         NULL
2   TV2   www.url.com  some_icon  Facebook_URL         NULL
3   TV3   www.url.com  some_icon          NULL  Twitter_URL
```

If this is not possible with native SQL Server mechanisms, maybe PostgreSQL can do it, or other RMDBS

PS. My question is not duplicate of [Parse JSON in TSQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2867501/parse-json-in-tsql). I need to find out the way to parse that heterogeneous json in rows

Comment: What are you trying to do? do you want to import this json structure into a SQL Server table or what?

Comment: I need to write a query for extracting JSON from column, and creating dynamically columns. All details in description. Thank you!

Comment: It should be possible with SQL Server 2016 afaik [JSON Support in SQL Server 2016](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jocapc/archive/2015/05/16/json-support-in-sql-server-2016.aspx)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Parse JSON in TSQL](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2867501/parse-json-in-tsql)

Comment: There is concrete question about transformation, it's not so general question as in link above. Please correct me if I am wrong

Comment: @SpanishBoy Please let me know how you solved the problem. I am in a similar situation.

Comment: Don't remember :( how exactly, but solved

Answer (score 12):

In SQL Server 2016 you would be able to define schema at query time when you open json:

```
select id, name, url, icon, facebook, twitter
from tab
     cross apply openjson(value) 
                 with (url nvarchar(100), icon varbinary,
                       facebook nvarchar(100),twitter nvarchar(100))
```

Note that you cannot have dynamic return schema - you need to specify what fields should be returned in TVF. As an alternative you can use openjson without WITH clause to dynamically return all key:value pairs from the JSON object:

```
select id, name, json.[key], json.value
from tab
     cross apply openjson(value) as json
```

In this version, OPENJSON will return pivoted values. key:value pairs will not be returned as column:cell - each key:value pair will be returned in a separate rows:

```
ID Name key      value
1  TV1  URL      www.url.com
1  TV1  Icon     some_icon
2  TV2  URL      www.url.com
2  TV2  Icon     some_icon
2  TV3  Facebook Facebook_URL
3  TV3  URL      www.url.com
3  TV3  Icon     some_icon
3  TV3  Twitter  Twitter_URL
....
```

This will be also available in Azure SQL Database soon. In earlier version you will need to find or write some CLR TVF that parses JSON or use some extremely complicated T-SQL. I can recommend JsonSelect and json4sql if you want to use existing CLR solutions. 
Other alternative for older version of SQL Server is to use XML instead of JSON and use nodes() function.

Comment: This is the perfect answer. I guess maybe the OP went away

Answer (score 0):

Take a look and let us know if this post can help you

https://www.simple-talk.com/blogs/2013/03/26/sql-server-json-to-table-and-table-to-json/

Comment: Thanks! The main difficult issue for me right now, to iterate over heterogeneous JSON content for each row