# how to check longitude latitude database sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2012

i have longitude and latitude in geofence table how to check longitude and latitude in database level. if car longitude latitude are in Zone, update geofance column zones = 'car in zone area'

```
CREATE TRIGGER Tr_CheckGeoFance
ON CheckGeoFance
AFTER INSERT AS
BEGIN
Update tblgeofencing
Set CarZone ='Car In Zone Area'
END
GO
ShapesString ={"shapes":[{"type":"rectangle","color":"#1E90FF","bounds":{"northEast":{"lat":"32.379961464357315","lon":"70.99365234375"},"southWest":{"lat":"31.840232667909362","lon":"70.2685546875"}}}]}
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: Stop storing Lat/Lon in JSON and store it in as a Geography data type instead, it will make this an order of magnitude easier. Of course that does require SQL Server 2008 R2.

Comment: i am new in sql how do this

Comment: See here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc280766(v=sql.105).aspx

Comment: The stated JSON seems to represent an area, not a position. Is that the boundary of your geofence?

Comment: yes.how to show alert car in zone area

Comment: anyone have query related to this please help

Answer (score 0):

First You have to decode the ShapesString which is currently in json format and then find out the latitude and longitude out of the decoded json.
Then check the lat-long lie in your defined range to update the column.

Refer this to decode the json:-
[Parse JSON in TSQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2867501/parse-json-in-tsql)