# Recursive CTE for parsing JSON file

Tags: sql, json, t-sql, sql-server-2014, common-table-expression

I'm using SQL Server 2014 for parsing a JSON file and for that I think that a recursive CTE is convenient.

The JSON file is like this:

```
{
  "0": {
    "SalesOrderNumber": "CSVSO67695",
    "SalesOrderDetailID": 97971,
    "OrderDate": "2014-03-05 00:00:00.000",
    "ProductNumber": "WB-H098",
    "Quantity": 1,
    "LineTotal": 4.99,
    "CustomerType": "Individual",
    "TestData_1": "Sales extract OK!",
    "TestData_2": 255
  },
  "1": {
    "SalesOrderNumber": "CSVSO53485",
    "SalesOrderDetailID": 47747,
    "OrderDate": "2013-07-31 00:00:00.000",
    "ProductNumber": "SJ-0194-L",
    "Quantity": 10,
    "LineTotal": 323.94,
    "CustomerType": "Store",
    "TestData_1": "Sales extract OK!",
    "TestData_2": 255
  },
  "2": {
    "SalesOrderNumber": "CSVSO52248",
    "SalesOrderDetailID": 43809,
    "OrderDate": "2013-07-07 00:00:00.000",
    "ProductNumber": "TT-M928",
    "Quantity": 1,
    "LineTotal": 4.99,
    "CustomerType": "Individual",
    "TestData_1": "Sales extract OK!",
    "TestData_2": 255
  }
```

}

Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: Could you perhaps provide your required output schema? Is it Key,Value? Also, please indicate if the code needs to perform exclusively on this JSON schema, or on a variety.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Parse JSON in TSQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2867501/parse-json-in-tsql)

Answer (score 0):

You don't need recursion for this. Grab a copy of [delimitedSplit8K](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/Tally+Table/72993/) and do this:

```
declare @json varchar(8000) =
'{
"0": {
"SalesOrderNumber": "CSVSO67695",
"SalesOrderDetailID": 97971,
"OrderDate": "2014-03-05 00:00:00.000",
"ProductNumber": "WB-H098",
"Quantity": 1,
"LineTotal": 4.99,
"CustomerType": "Individual",
"TestData_1": "Sales extract OK!",
"TestData_2": 255
},
"1": {
"SalesOrderNumber": "CSVSO53485",
"SalesOrderDetailID": 47747,
"OrderDate": "2013-07-31 00:00:00.000",
"ProductNumber": "SJ-0194-L",
"Quantity": 10,
"LineTotal": 323.94,
"CustomerType": "Store",
"TestData_1": "Sales extract OK!",
"TestData_2": 255
},
"2": {
"SalesOrderNumber": "CSVSO52248",
"SalesOrderDetailID": 43809,
"OrderDate": "2013-07-07 00:00:00.000",
"ProductNumber": "TT-M928",
"Quantity": 1,
"LineTotal": 4.99,
"CustomerType": "Individual",
"TestData_1": "Sales extract OK!",
"TestData_2": 255
  }
}';

select
  jsonItemId,
  item,
  attrib,
  attribValue
from 
(
  select 
    jsonItemId = sum(sign(jsonItemIdPrep)) over (order by itemnumber),
    ItemNumber, 
    item,
    attrib      = ltrim(replace(substring(item, 1, sep.pos-1),'"','')),
    attribValue = replace(ltrim(replace(substring(item, sep.pos+1, len(item)),'"','')),',',''),
    jsonItemIdPrep
  from 
  (
    select ItemNumber, item, jsonItemIdPrep =  
      case 
        when item like '%"[0-9]": {%'  
          or item like '%"[0-9][0-9]": {%' 
          or item like '%"[0-9][0-9][0-9]": {%' -- 1,2 or 3 digits
        then substring(item, v.ps, charindex('"', item, v.ps)- v.ps)
      end
    from dbo.DelimitedSplit8K(replace(@json,char(10),''), char(13))
    cross apply (values (charindex('"',item)+1)) v(ps)
    where ItemNumber > 1 and item not like '%}' and item not like '%},'
  ) x
  cross apply (values (charindex(':', item))) sep(pos)
  cross apply (values (replace(substring(item, 1, sep.pos-1),'"',''))) p(xxx)
) x
where jsonItemIdPrep is null;
```

**Results**

```
jsonItemId  item                                                  attrib                        attribValue
----------- ----------------------------------------------------- ----------------------------- -----------------------------------
0           "SalesOrderNumber": "CSVSO67695",                 SalesOrderNumber              CSVSO67695
0           "SalesOrderDetailID": 97971,                      SalesOrderDetailID            97971
0           "OrderDate": "2014-03-05 00:00:00.000",           OrderDate                     2014-03-05 00:00:00.000
0           "ProductNumber": "WB-H098",                       ProductNumber                 WB-H098
0           "Quantity": 1,                                    Quantity                      1
0           "LineTotal": 4.99,                                LineTotal                     4.99
0           "CustomerType": "Individual",                     CustomerType                  Individual
0           "TestData_1": "Sales extract OK!",                TestData_1                    Sales extract OK!
0           "TestData_2": 255                                 TestData_2                    255
1           "SalesOrderNumber": "CSVSO53485",                 SalesOrderNumber              CSVSO53485
1           "SalesOrderDetailID": 47747,                      SalesOrderDetailID            47747
1           "OrderDate": "2013-07-31 00:00:00.000",           OrderDate                     2013-07-31 00:00:00.000
1           "ProductNumber": "SJ-0194-L",                     ProductNumber                 SJ-0194-L
1           "Quantity": 10,                                   Quantity                      10
1           "LineTotal": 323.94,                              LineTotal                     323.94
1           "CustomerType": "Store",                          CustomerType                  Store
1           "TestData_1": "Sales extract OK!",                TestData_1                    Sales extract OK!
1           "TestData_2": 255                                 TestData_2                    255
2           "SalesOrderNumber": "CSVSO52248",                 SalesOrderNumber              CSVSO52248
2           "SalesOrderDetailID": 43809,                      SalesOrderDetailID            43809
2           "OrderDate": "2013-07-07 00:00:00.000",           OrderDate                     2013-07-07 00:00:00.000
2           "ProductNumber": "TT-M928",                       ProductNumber                 TT-M928
2           "Quantity": 1,                                    Quantity                      1
2           "LineTotal": 4.99,                                LineTotal                     4.99
2           "CustomerType": "Individual",                     CustomerType                  Individual
2           "TestData_1": "Sales extract OK!",                TestData_1                    Sales extract OK!
2           "TestData_2": 255                                 TestData_2                    255
```