# How to use OPENJSON or a compatible equivalent in SQL Server 2014?

Tags: json, sql-server, sql-server-2014, sql-server-2017

[I am aware OPENJSON is a new feature in SQL Server 2016.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/openjson-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)

I currently have the stored procedure shown below working for SQL Server 2017, but I cannot figure out a way to make it work on SQL Server 2014 or find a compatible equivalent.

The current error I get is as follows:

> Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'WITH'.
>
> Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'with'. If this statement is a common table expression, an xmlnamespaces clause or a change tracking context clause, the previous statement must be terminated with a semicolon.

My code:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE ProcedureName 
    @submissionID INT
AS
    DECLARE @submission_FormDefn AS INT
    DECLARE @Defn_json AS NVARCHAR(MAX)
    DECLARE @Subm_json AS NVARCHAR(MAX) 

    SELECT  
        @Subm_json = [jsonPost],  
        @submission_FormDefn = [FormDefn_Id] 
    FROM 
        form_submissions 
    WHERE
        id = @submissionID

     SET @Defn_json = (SELECT [data] 
                       FROM form_defns 
                       WHERE id = @submission_FormDefn)

     SELECT 
         dd.name, dd.label, dd.type, V.VALUE 
     FROM
         [dbo].[form_submissions_VALUES] V
     INNER JOIN 
         OPENJSON(@Defn_json) WITH (name varchar(MAX) '$.name',
                                    label varchar(MAX) '$.label',
                                    type varchar(MAX) '$.type') dd ON V.field = dd.name
     WHERE  
         type IN ('one', 'two', 'three') 
         AND v.FormSubmission_Id = @submissionID
GO
```

Comment: Actually, OPENJSON was introduced in SQL 2016.  But have a look here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2867501/parse-json-in-tsql

Comment: You could convert json to xml and then use XML, this would be an alternative approach. (google json to xml sql function)

Comment: Thanks for the correction. And I've read through all the comments and answers in that link, none seem to be helpful unfortunately. @squillman

Comment: What exactly are you looking for?  Phil Factor's answer gives you an alternative.  There is no direct alternative to OPENJSON in SQL 2014.  It simply doesn't support parsing JSON natively.

Comment: A possible function that could. I apologize I didn't mean to come off as rude. In that link, it was just a lot of help towards SQL 2016 and not 2014. Perhaps I'm not looking in the right places. @squillman

Comment: @iSR5 thank you for the suggestion. I'm currently dabbling with it now.

Comment: No worries, wasn't trying to imply you were sounding rude!  Here's the directly link to Phil Factor's function.  It's a bit of a read... https://www.red-gate.com/simple-talk/sql/t-sql-programming/consuming-json-strings-in-sql-server/