# How to I return multiple rows from a nested JSON object stored in a table

Tags: json, sql-server, sql-server-json

Given the following JSON stored in a `nvarchar(max)` column, how to generate the table shown? I can make is for if the nested object is an `[]`, an array, but not a structure {}

```
DECLARE @JSON AS NVARCHAR(MAX);

SET  @JSON = N'{
    "ACCOUNT": 1
,   "USERS" : {
        "BOB" : 1
    ,   "JOHN" : 2
    ,   "RODGER" : 3
    }
}';


SELECT JSON_QUERY(@JSON,'$.USERS')


ACCOUNT   USER     USER_VALUE
================================
    1     BOB          1
    1     JOHN         2
    1     RODGER       3
```

Comment: Why do you want to do this?. It doesn't seem like something that SQL is suited to.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Parse JSON in TSQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2867501/parse-json-in-tsql)

Answer (score 2):

You may try with the next approach using `OPENJSON` (with an explicit structure for `ACCOUNT` and `USERS` columns) and additional `CROSS APPLY`:

```
-- JSON
DECLARE @JSON AS NVARCHAR(MAX);
SET  @JSON = N'{
    "ACCOUNT": 1
,   "USERS" : {
        "BOB" : 1
    ,   "JOHN" : 2
    ,   "RODGER" : 3
    }
}';

-- Statement
SELECT i.ACCOUNT, v.[key] AS [USER], v.[value] AS USER_VALUE
FROM OPENJSON(@json) 
WITH (
   ACCOUNT int '$.ACCOUNT',
   USERS nvarchar(max) '$.USERS' AS JSON
) i
CROSS APPLY (
   SELECT *
   FROM OPENJSON(i.USERS)
) v
```

Output:

```
ACCOUNT USER    USER_VALUE
1       BOB     1
1       JOHN    2
1       RODGER  3
```