# Manage Json in a table

Tags: sql, json, sql-server, sql-server-2016

I have a table like this:

```
TABLE myTable(identifier nvarchar(10) primary key, jsonfield nvarchar(max))
```

In the table there is 1 record like this:

[image: Example of data within the table]

Can you help to findout a single query to output something like this within a view? It is SQL Server.
[image: Example of output from the query]

Comment: Which database engine are you using? Please tag it in the question.

Comment: You won't be able to do it with a sql alone at least with a single statement. Your best bet to actually change how you store your data in  the database.  It looks well structured - so parse it before storing and store is as a structured data.

Comment: it is sqlserver

Comment: unfortuntally i can modify the way data is stored :(

Comment: @AleksG many databases support JSON and JSON operations in SQL. [SQL Server](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/json/json-data-sql-server) does.

Comment: Which SQL Server version are you using?

Comment: sql server 2016

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Parse JSON in TSQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2867501/parse-json-in-tsql)

Comment: Sample data as screen shots. :( Help us to help you by including sample data as text.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use `OPENJSON()` with explicit schema (the `WITH` clause with columns definitions) to parse the `Cities` JSON array stored in the `jsonfield` column:

```
SELECT t.identifier, j.Name, j.Population 
FROM myTable t
CROSS APPLY OPENJSON(t.jsonfield, '$.Cities') WITH (
   Name varchar(50) '$.Name',
   Population int '$.Population'
) j
```