# Spark SQL Return data from string field held json Dictionary style

Tags: apache-spark-sql

I have a data frame with a large string field in it with a load of questionnaire questions and answers held in a json Dictionary style pairs, the questionnaires vary in length and do not always the same questions.

Using Spark SQL how can I get the questions and answers out of the string field `Responses` so i have a 3 column list of
`"CustomerID, Questions, Answers"`

So from this

```
CustomerID     Responses
1              [{"question1":"answer 1"},{"question 2":"answer2"}]
2              [{"question1":"answer 1a"},{"question 2":"answer2b"}]
3              [{"question1":"answer 1b"},{"question 3":"answer3"}]
```

to resolve to

```
CustomerID   Questions  Answers
1            question1  answer1
1            question2  answer2
2            question1  answer1a
2            question2  answer2b 
3            question1  answer1b 
3            question3  answer3
```

I'm looking at lateral view explode but i just cant see how to use it

```
%sql
select r.ID,
       lat.question,
       lat.answer

from table r 
   lateral view outer explode(r.responses) lat as question, answer
```

error says
 `cannot resolve 'explode(r.responses)' due to data type mismatch: input to function explode should be array or map type, not string'`

Answer (score 0):

try these resources:

[JSON SQL Processing MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/json/json-data-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver15)

[SQLSHack Example](https://www.sqlshack.com/how-to-parse-json-in-sql-server/)

after reading that, it would be simple to create the SQL query

Comment: All the examples show ```label : value``` where as the data i have is ```value:value``` pairs how do i extract that out without explicitly calling the label value because I want to group them into 2 columns not many columns

Answer (score 0):

You can parse json data while selecting from sql
See example

```
      Select * from parseJSON('{
           "Person":
             {
                "firstName": "John",
                "lastName": "Smith",
                "age": 25,
               }
           "Address":
              {
                 "streetAddress":"21 2nd Street",
                 "city":"New York",
                 "state":"NY",
                "postalCode":"10021"
              },
           "PhoneNumbers":
             {
                 "home":"212 555-1234",
                 "fax":"646 555-4567"
               }
         }
   }  )
```

Use parseJSON() procedure

[Parse JSON in TSQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2867501/parse-json-in-tsql)

Comment: That isnt the data shape i have though

Comment: Yes you can change it to fit yours. All I wanted is to point you to the sql procedure which I think can do the job