# SQL to add quotes to a attribute inside JSON

Tags: sql, salesforce-marketing-cloud

I have a table (DE in SFMC) with the following schema

### Incoming_data

```
Id -- Text(40)
Data_Json -- Text(4000)
```

The field Data_Json contains data in JSON format.
Sample data shown below

```
ID                      DATA_JSON
------------------      ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
123456                   {'EMPLOYEE_ID':'12345678','EMPLOYEE_DEPT':'SALES', 'EMPLOYEE_START_DATE':'2022-08-01','EMPLOYEE_HIRE_DATE':'2022-07-15','EMPLOYEE_NAME':'TEST','EMPLOYEE_DEPT_NO':1,'EMPLOYEE_DEPT_CAT':'SL_LOB', 'EMPLOYEE_EMAIL_ADD':'ABCTEST@DOESNOTEXIST.ca','EMPLOYEE_TYPE':'F'}
 
222333                    {'EMPLOYEE_ID':'13578912','EMPLOYEE_START_DATE':'2022-09-01','EMPLOYEE_HIRE_DATE':'2022-08-15','EMPLOYEE_NAME':'TEST2','EMPLOYEE_EMAIL_ADD':'TEST2@DOESNOTEXIST.ca','EMPLOYEE_TYPE':'C'}
 
444555                    {'EMPLOYEE_ID':'23134587','EMPLOYEE_START_DATE':'2022-11-15','EMPLOYEE_HIRE_DATE':'2022-10-15','EMPLOYEE_NAME':'TEST3','EMPLOYEE_EMAIL_ADD':'TEST3@DOESNOTEXIST.ca','EMPLOYEE_TYPE':'P'}
 
666777                    {'EMPLOYEE_ID':'44555678','EMPLOYEE_DEPT':'MARKET', 'EMPLOYEE_START_DATE':'2022-06-01','EMPLOYEE_HIRE_DATE':'2022-05-15','EMPLOYEE_NAME':'TEST4','EMPLOYEE_DEPT_NO':3,'EMPLOYEE_DEPT_CAT':'PT_MAKT', 'EMPLOYEE_EMAIL_ADD':'TEST4@DOESNOTEXIST.ca','EMPLOYEE_TYPE':'F'}
```

Using SQL, How to modify the `EMPLOYEE_DEPT_NO` field in the `DATA_JSON` to add single quotes to the data
I.e. how to add single quotes to as below

```
'EMPLOYEE_DEPT_NO':'3'
```

Any help is much appreciated

I want the value of attribute inside JSON to be encoded with single quotes

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Parse JSON in TSQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2867501/parse-json-in-tsql)

Comment: Please update your question to include your query -- even if it doesn't work.

Comment: For a numerical value (integer or floating point), unquoted is valid json

Answer (score 0):

Select the field, convert it to (VAR)CHAR, and update it:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS SAMPLE;
CREATE TABLE SAMPLE (
  ID TEXT,
  DATA_JSON NVARCHAR(MAX));

INSERT INTO SAMPLE VALUES
('123456', N'{"EMPLOYEE_ID":"12345678",
              "EMPLOYEE_DEPT":"SALES", 
              "EMPLOYEE_START_DATE":"2022-08-01",
              "EMPLOYEE_HIRE_DATE":"2022-07-15",
              "EMPLOYEE_NAME":"TEST",
              "EMPLOYEE_DEPT_NO":1,
              "EMPLOYEE_DEPT_CAT":"SL_LOB", 
              "EMPLOYEE_EMAIL_ADD":"ABCTEST@DOESNOTEXIST.ca",
              "EMPLOYEE_TYPE":"F"}');



SELECT * FROM SAMPLE;
-- Selecting the numeric field:
SELECT JSON_VALUE(DATA_JSON, '$.EMPLOYEE_DEPT_NO')  FROM SAMPLE;

-- Updating the numeric field using CAST:
UPDATE SAMPLE
SET DATA_JSON = JSON_MODIFY(DATA_JSON, '$.EMPLOYEE_DEPT_NO', CAST(JSON_VALUE(DATA_JSON, '$.EMPLOYEE_DEPT_NO') as VARCHAR(8))) FROM SAMPLE;

SELECT * FROM SAMPLE;
```

output:

```
(1 row affected)
ID                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                               DATA_JSON
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
123456                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                           {"EMPLOYEE_ID":"12345678",
              "EMPLOYEE_DEPT":"SALES", 
              "EMPLOYEE_START_DATE":"2022-08-01",
              "EMPLOYEE_HIRE_DATE":"2022-07-15",
              "EMPLOYEE_NAME":"TEST",
              "EMPLOYEE_DEPT_NO":1,
          

(1 row affected)


----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
1

(1 row affected)

(1 row affected)

ID                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                               DATA_JSON
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
123456                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                           {"EMPLOYEE_ID":"12345678",
              "EMPLOYEE_DEPT":"SALES", 
              "EMPLOYEE_START_DATE":"2022-08-01",
              "EMPLOYEE_HIRE_DATE":"2022-07-15",
              "EMPLOYEE_NAME":"TEST",
              "EMPLOYEE_DEPT_NO":"1",
        

(1 row affected)


Completion time: 2023-06-11T15:43:12.1263503+02:00
```

Comment: You can't do any of this in SFMC.

Comment: Ok, but (I do hope) there is a way of modifying an element in a JSON file, casting that value to an alphanumeric datatype ?

Answer (score -1):

To change the EMPLOYEE_DEPT_NO field in the DATA_JSON column to include single quotes, check the following query:-

```
UPDATE Incoming_data
SET Data_Json = REPLACE(Data_Json, '"EMPLOYEE_DEPT_NO":', "'EMPLOYEE_DEPT_NO':'")
WHERE Data_Json LIKE '%"EMPLOYEE_DEPT_NO":%';
```